# integrating modified gamma functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, gamma-function

I have an integral that looks like an incomplete gamma function, with another factor in front
\begin{equation}
I = \int_x^y \frac{1}{a^{c+1}}[1-t]^bt^ce^{-\frac{t}{a^2}}dt
\end{equation}
Is there a way to evaluate an integral of this form? In this case $c\in \mathbb Z$ and $b,a\in \

Comment: If $b$ is integer you can write out $(1-t)^b$ using binomial coefficients, write the integral as the sum of all monomials and evaluate each one individually using $\Gamma$-functions

Comment: @User123456789 Could you expand that into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
$$(1-t)^bt^c = \sum_{i=0}^b\begin{pmatrix}b\\i\end{pmatrix}(-1)^{i}t^{c+i}=\sum_i d_it^{c+i}$$
Then we can evaluate the integral of the sum as the sum of the integrals

$$\sum_i\int_x^y\frac{d_i}{a^{c+1}}t^{c+i}e^{-\frac{t}{a^2}}dt $$

Which can be integrated using (incomplete) $\Gamma$ functions.

Comment: Also note that the first fraction in the integral is just a constant, so has no effect on the calculations.